# Japanese kun'yomi with final N?

Tags: japanese, phonotactics

It is thought that the moraic post-vocalic consonant [N], spelt with ん, appeared in Japanese under the Chinese influence, with the influx of borrowings. Are there any *kun*-readings in Japanese that have the final ん? And with what processes could they have emerged?

Comment: Did you try asking this on Japanese SE?

Comment: I'm not sure about what counts as "language-specific grammar and usage questions"; this is language-specific, but is not a grammar or usage question.  It's rather about historical phonology.

Comment: @WiccanKarnak how is this about "grammar and usage"? It's about phonotactics in different strata of the Japanese lexicon, and their historical development

Comment: P.S. I am just an yearling here and don't know how thin the line is on that one. But, I do see if the question is not edited to be more Linguistics-in-general specific, it can be transferred to Japanese SE with leobiko's answer. I was planning on a more carefully edited re-opening of the question after editing, but if there is a consensus I will most definitely retract my vote on this otherwise amazingly thought/ brought out question

Answer (score 10):

*Kun*-readings are an orthographic notation for the native lexical stratum (*Yamato-kotoba*).  So the underlying question is, are there native morphemes with closed syllables (that is, with a consonant at the end)? Originally, no; Old Japanese was a CV language (syllables started with a consonant and ended in a vowel).  However, what are currently voiced consonants used to be [prenasalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenasalized_consonant) (as they still are in certain dialects, e.g. in Tōhoku); so that ざ was /ⁿza/, ば was /ᵐba/ etc.  Modern *tanabata* used to be pronounced *tanambada*.

Around Heian times, this worked in tandem with the new Chinese layer to introduce the moraic, syllable-final N-consonant.  Consider for example the *onbin* sound changes:

- A verb like *hanasu* inflected to the i-form to get the suffix *-te*, generating *hanasite*.
- A verb like *hanatu*, likewise, was *hanatite*; but elision of the vowel rendered it *hanatte* – a new geminated form that was only possible after CCV syllables became part of the system, along with Chinese consonant-final loans.
- A verb like *asobu > asobite* also underwent elision – but recall that the Old pronunciation was *asombite*; the pre-nasal survived elision while the voicing assimilated to the *-te*, generating *asonde*.

So Yamato morphemes got syllable-final N due to internal processes, at the same time that the Chinese wave brought another syllable-final nasal (and not just the nasal; syllable-final /p/, /k/, /t/ survived in *on* loans—the last two for many centuries).  One way of explaining this is, multiple pressures changed the syllable structure from a simple CV to a moraic system, and once the language was moraic, syllable-final nasals could be generated even in the Yamato stratum (along with other moraic structures: geminated consonants and diphthongs).

However, the above aren't *kun*-readings proper, since verb inflections aren't normally written as *kanji* readings.  Still, there are *kun* readings with ん in them:

- Some are the result of simple elision, like 何 *nan* < *nani*, 神 *kan* < *kami*, 懇ろ *nengoro* < *nemogoro*, or 女 *onna* < *womina*.
- Some are readings resulting from the morphophonological processes described above, like 冠 *kanmuri* < *kauburi* *[kãw̃ᵐburi], or 芳しい *kambasii* < かぐはしい **kangubasii*.
- Some are ultimately Chinese morphemes that ended up counting as *kun* in the orthography, like 鞄 *kaban* < ?Ch. 夾板 **keap-paen*; or  the *don* of 丼 *donburi* (etymology unclear but probably Chinese *don-* + Japanese *-furi*; standard view traces *don* to 貪 **thom* "covet" in 慳貪  **kʰˠɛn thom* > J. *kendon*, "greed, gluttony", since *kendon-ya* is attested for *donburi* sellers; alternatively from 緞子 *donsu*, "damask").

Sources:

- Frellesvig, *A History of the Japanese Language*.
- The *Kokugo Daijiten*.
- [gogen.all-guide](http://gogen-allguide.com/)
- Baxter-Sargat Middle Chinese reconstruction.
- The Jōyō Kanji table and the Kanjidic file for kun-readings.